# JMESPath query using the contains function is giving a syntax error

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, jmespath

I am searching through Azure container and want to filter out blobs ending with certain suffixes. When I use the `--query` parameter with a JMESPath `contains` function, it is giving me an error.

When I run the command

```bash
az storage blob list \
    --account-name $account_name \
    --account-key $key \
    --num-results $numResults \
    --show-next-marker \
    --container-name $container_name \
    --query [].name
```

it runs without any error.

When I change the query to

```bash
    --query [].name[?contains(@,'R00005006')=='true']
```

or

```bash
    --query [].name[?contains(@,'R00005006')]
```

I get this error:

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: ```--query '[].name[?contains(@,`R00005006`)]'```

Comment: this modification runs the query and gives no error but gives me blank output. Why is it not matching the string?

Comment: Could you show a minimal JSON output of the az command without the query filter?

Comment: Also, what are you looking like for a result? Just a list of names of the whole JSON object of the blob?

Comment: It was working fine but now I am getting no result of any query. Does it mean that my CLI is not connected to the Azure Cloud? Is there a better way to connect to the Azure cloud other than az login?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the query in quotes for it to be parsed correctly by the command prompt as well as create a projection for it be properly parsed.

```bash
az storage blob list \
    --account-name $account_name \
    --account-key $key \
    --num-results $numResults \
    --show-next-marker \
    --container-name $container_name \
    --query "[*].name | [?contains(@, 'R00005006') == `true`]"
```

Take note that `true` is surrounded with a backtick.

Comment: Thanks but this one was working without problem. It is this query that is giving me 
error.
--query "[].[name?contains(@,12878)]"

Comment: I've update the answer with the fix for the query.

Comment: thanks, it didn't work but this did:
--query "[].name | [?contains(@, '12878')]"

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the whole blob object content, then you should have your condition on the array of blob objects:

```
[?contains(name, `R00005006`)]
```

So, in you Azure command:

```bash
az storage blob list \
  --account-name $account_name \
  --account-key $key \
  --num-results $numResults \
  --show-next-marker \
  --container-name $container_name \
  --query '[?contains(name, `R00005006`)]'
```

---

If you are just looking for a list of names indeed, you have to stop the list projection created by `.name` with a [pipe expression](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions):

```
[].name | [?contains(@, `R00005006`)]
```

So, in your Azure command:

```bash
az storage blob list \
  --account-name $account_name \
  --account-key $key \
  --num-results $numResults \
  --show-next-marker \
  --container-name $container_name \
  --query '[].name | [?contains(@, `R00005006`)]'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me..
--query "[].name | [?contains(@, '12878')]"

continuation questions, 
1. how can I search for multiple matching patterns? like, 12878*vcf.gz or 12878*hard-filtered.vcf.gz and so on. 
2. Is there a way to do for loop if I have a whole list of numbers to match for those patterns, or I should simply write a bash script and run this code multiple times.

TIA

Comment: You can definitely have a or `||` and/or an and `&&`, or a mix of both in that filter, e.g.: `[].name | [?(contains(@, '123') && contains(@, 'vcf.gz')) || (contains(@, '345') && contains(@, 'hard-filtered.vcf.gz'))]`.

Comment: As for the for loop, no, you could probably do a more complex contains that fits your need but that would defiantly need more input from your side (i.e.: an example JSON output of that Azure command and a desired output).

Comment: awesome.. That helped a lot. another leading question: Is there a way that I can query for substring ending with a pattern or not matching the pattern?

Comment: Apart from `contains`, you also have a [`starts_with`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#starts-with) and a [`ends_with`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#ends-with) functions that you can use the same way, yes.